# how to get some of column values in monthwise using dates in month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

presently I have this table:

```
---------------------------------
date        | value1 | value2 |
-----------------------------------
01-01-2017  |  20    | 10 
02-01-2017  |  30    | 10
03-01-2017  |  40    | 20
01-02-2017  |  50    | 5
02-02-2017  |  10    | 15
03-02-2017  |  10    | 20
```

and I need this output:

```
Date      | Value1| Value2|
-------------------------
Jan-2017  | 90   |  40
Feb-2017  | 70   |  40
```

Can anyone please provide me the appropriate query?

Comment: Can you please provide us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: select CAST (Date as MONTH),SUM(Value1) as 'Sum1' from sample1 group by CAST(Date as MONTH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fine with 2008

```
WITH CTE AS (
           SELECT  
           SUBSTRING(CAST(DATENAME(MM, DATE) AS VARCHAR(15)), 1, 3) 
           + '-' +
           CAST(DATEPART(YY, DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Date, DATEPART(MM, Date) AS MonthOrder,
           Value1 ,   
           Value2
           FROM tblTestTableDates
           )

 SELECT Date, SUM(Value1) AS Value1 , SUM(Value2) AS Value2
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Date , MonthOrder
    ORDER BY MonthOrder
```

CTE looks cleaner, another approach without it

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM, DATE)) + '-' +
 CAST(DATEPART(YY, DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)), 
SUM(Value1) AS Value1, 
SUM(Value2) AS Value2
 FROM tblTestTableDates
 GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM, DATE)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(YY,DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)), DATEPART(MM, DATE)
 ORDER BY DATEPART(MM, DATE)
```

Comment: its working Fine. Thank you !! and  is there any possibility to order months by calender wise like jan ,feb, march..etc.,

Comment: Hi, I have amended both queries to include order by month. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by  the Date part `Year-Month` and get the sum of `value1` and `value2`. This is accomplished by:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATE, 20) DATE
    ,SUM(value1) Value1
    ,SUM(value2) Value2
FROM myTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATE, 20)
```

if you want to display name of Month instead of number, try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT( date,'MMM yyyy') DATE
    ,SUM(value1) Value1
    ,SUM(value2) Value2
FROM myTable
GROUP BY FORMAT( date,'MMM yyyy')
```

Comment: its working fine But I need to Display month name instead of month order

Comment: Iam Using SqlSever 2008..when i Execute the Query It Shows Error like this..                                                                                                                     Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Yes, my fault, FORMAT is not supported on SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b-%Y') as date , value1,value2 from ( select month(date),sum(value1) value1,sum(value2) value2,year(date) ,date from test
group by month(date),year(date))aa

Comment: When i Execute this....Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.